# Install Twisted in Mac OS/X 1.8.5 for Python 2.7

Tags: python, macos, installation, twisted

Some version, first:

mac osx version:

```
$ system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 12.5.0
      Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
      Boot Mode: Normal
```

python:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
```

zope:

```
>>> import zope
>>> zope.__path__
['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/zope', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/zope']
```

So.. Max 1.8.5 with python 2.7 and zope 4.1

then.. **the problem**:

```
>>> import twisted
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    _checkRequirements()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/__init__.py", line 51, in _checkRequirements
    raise ImportError(required + ".")
ImportError: Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later.
```

For sure I have messed up something with `sudo` executing python setup.py install, easy_install, pip, and other but.. the question is:

How to install an updated version of twisted?

Comment: The fact that the paths in your traceback say "`twisted/__init__.py`" suggests that you're getting this error because your current directory has a "twisted" in it.  What happens if you `cd /tmp` and try to import Twisted?

Comment: yes sorry, I was on the directory where I have cloned the repo. The same, I have updated the question

Comment: It could be helpful to include "sys.path". I suggest checking if you could import zope.interface and what is zope.interface.__path__

Comment: zope.interface.__path__ : `['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/zope/interface']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X 10.8 comes with Zope Interface 3.5.1.  However, when you installed Twisted into `/Library`, you didn't install a newer importable version of Zope Interface at the same time.

Delete the version of Twisted you've installed.  OS X 10.8 already comes with Twisted 12.0, which may be good enough for what you're doing.  If you need a newer version, install it into a virtualenv and work with it there.  https://pip2014.com/ can get you started with the requisite tooling to do this *without* screwing up your system with `sudo` ;-)

Comment: Ok good I'm diving into it. Anyway now without virtualenv I'd like to restore the original version of twisted. any advice?

Comment: ok never mind, I have downloaded from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Twisted/12.0.0#downloads) and executed `sudo python setup.py install` seems to work now. Thank you very much to point me into pip2014.

Comment: Honestly, after [this post](http://www.ianbicking.org/blog/2014/09/professional-transitions.html) I thought that pip was no more in development. Can you advice me some links where to get informed about it? I'm new to python community and I think that a system like node.js is really handy: it install all libs of a specified version and you don't have to worry about any kind of compatibility between libs in the actual environment. It is like `virtualenv` done automatically behind the hood, if I have understood correctly.. do you have some nice article about it? or blog post, or anything else!

Comment: Ian Bicking has had nothing whatsoever to do with pip for years.  That blog post doesn't even mention pip.  What made you think it was no longer under development?

Comment: Basically if you set up `pip2014` (which is to say: virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, setuptools, pip, and wheel), you just do `mkvirtualenv foo` to create an environment, `workon foo` to activate that environment, and when the environment is active, `pip install twisted` to install the most recent version of Twisted.  Once installed, while that environment is active (any time you type "`workon foo` in a shell) the newer versions of `twistd`, `trial`, etc, will be on your `$PATH`, and the "`python` on your `$PATH` will be one that can import the newer Twisted.